# How to return prepared query result from a procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a use case that requires the creation of a temporary table with a unique name from within a stored procedure. The only way I have found to execute queries with a dynamic table name is to prepare the query:

```
SET @d=CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table_', case); 
PREPARE q from @d;
EXECUTE q;
```

This works well enough, but I cannot figure out how to return the result set. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything extra to return the result set.  It's enough to EXECUTE the prepared query.  The result set of that query execution will automatically become the result set of the stored procedure.

```
mysql> DELIMITER !!
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE p()
    -> BEGIN
    ->  SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT ', '123 as foo');
    ->  PREPARE q FROM @sql;
    ->  EXECUTE q;
    -> END!!
mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> CALL p;
+-----+
| foo |
+-----+
| 123 |
+-----+
```

---

Re your comment: it might be this bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20028 which was fixed.
You may correct the issue by upgrading.

> Noted in 5.0.30 (not 5.0.29), 5.1.13 changelogs.
>
> With SQL_MODE=TRADITIONAL, MySQL incorrectly aborted on warnings 
>   within stored routines and triggers.

Also see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7499/function-returning-no-data-zero-rows-fetched-selected-or-processed-in-mysq

Comment: That is what I thought too, and tried that. I get "ERROR 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed". If I do a "SELECT * FROM table_123" I get the data though.

Comment: I just feel silly now. I had a cursor in my procedure and forgot to declare the loop exit. I have been looking at this thing all day and just noticed it. Your answer is correct, thank you.

Comment: Glad you found the answer!  Don't feel silly, we've all been there.  :)

Comment: This doesn't return the prepared statement. It returns the resultset from an execution of the prepared statement.

Comment: @dolmen You are correct, as far as I know there is no way for a MySQL stored procedure to return a handle to the prepared statement. I don't think that's what this question was about.